# In the following code how can I initialize a class member without using dummy values?

Tags: c++

// Example program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

class A{
    public:
        A(int tempY){
            y = tempY;
        }
        int y = 0;
};

class B{
    public:
        B(A tempZ){
            z = tempZ.y;
        }
        A z;

};

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    A objA(x);
    B objB(objA);
    std::cout << "y = " << objB.z << "!\n";
}
```

Build at:
http://cpp.sh/3yj2

There is an error in class B because I haven't passed a constructor parameter to member z.
I don't want to initialize it with a dummy value, is there a way to only use constructor parameters to build member z, and how do I tell z to use B's constructor parameters?

If I'm missing a fundamental aspect of C++ please let me know I'm just starting out.

Comment: This isn't RAII. And you need to initialize `z` in the initializer-list if it has no default constructor. This is how it would look: `B(A tempZ) : z(tempZ) { }`. You should also take a const lvalue-reference to the parameter.

Comment: @0x499602D2: What's non-RAII about it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because he's not managing an allocated resource's lifetime through `B`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: `A z` is an allocated resource.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So that means this is RAII?

Comment: @0x499602D2: What does "this is RAII" mean?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Does he manage an allocated resource's lifetime through `B`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What about dynamically-allocated?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Of course not. Can you not see the code?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So does *not* managing a dynamically-allocated object's lifetime through the lifetime of some wrapping class like `B` constitute this *not* being RAII?

Comment: @0x499602D2: What are you talking about? Every resource that `B` encapsulates is acquired on construction and released on destruction. That is the very definition of the RAII principle. I don't see the problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use initializer lists like this

```
class B{
    public:
        B(A tempZ) : z(tempZ) {
        }
        A z;
};
```

This way z will be initialized with a new instance of A created by the copy constructor.